# iCloud upload progress and keys

Tags: ios, icloud

I'm trying to push a file to iCloud from one of my apps but sometimes there is no way to track if the file is already on iCloud or not. After marking the file as ubiquitous I have a method that periodically checks the status of the files via a NSMetadataQuery. When I get the results back I use these keys for the status of the file:

```
NSNumber *isUploaded = [file valueForAttribute:NSMetadataUbiquitousItemIsUploadedKey];
NSNumber *isUploading = [file valueForAttribute:NSMetadataUbiquitousItemIsUploadingKey];
NSNumber *uploadPercent = [file valueForAttribute:NSMetadataUbiquitousItemPercentUploadedKey];
```

This seems to work sometimes but in other times the isUploaded value is 0 and the isUploading value is also 0! The uploadPercent value is actually always 0. When I go into the 'Settings' app of my device and check the files for my app the files are already listed there so I'm not sure why the 'NSMetadataUbiquitousItemIsUploadedKey' key would return 0?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I guess either not a lot of people are using the iCloud APIs or nobody has found this issue before :(

Comment: Have you managed to track the progress of the file being uploaded to iCloud similar to WhatsApp Does.?

Answer (score 5):

I'm trying to do the same thing.  Per the iCloud guide, try NSURLUbiquitousItemIsUploadedKey instead of NSMetadataUbiquitousItemIsUploadedKey.  Let me know if that works for you.  I still haven't been able to get this working.  Here's the section from the guide:

**Determining the Transfer Status of a File or Directory**

Items you write to an iCloud container directory are transferred automatically to the iCloud server as quickly as possible. However, depending on the network and the type of device, a file might not be uploaded to the server or downloaded to a device immediately. In cases where you need to know the state of a file, you can use the `getResourceValue:forKey:error:` method of `NSURL` to retrieve the value for one of the following attributes:

`NSURLIsUbiquitousItemKey`—Indicates whether or not the item is stored in iCloud.

`NSURLUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey`—Indicates whether the current version of the item is downloaded and accessible.

`NSURLUbiquitousItemIsDownloadingKey`—Indicates whether the current version of the item is being downloaded and is not yet available.

`NSURLUbiquitousItemPercentDownloadedKey`—For an item being downloaded, indicates what percentage of the changes have already been downloaded. You can use this value to update progress bars.

`NSURLUbiquitousItemIsUploadedKey`—Indicates that locally made changes were successfully uploaded to the iCloud server.

`NSURLUbiquitousItemIsUploadingKey`—Indicates that locally made changes are being uploaded to the iCloud server now.

`NSURLUbiquitousItemPercentUploadedKey`—For an item being uploaded, indicates what percentage of the changes have already been uploaded to the server.

Although the iCloud server aggressively pulls changes your app makes locally, iOS devices typically do not pull changes from the server until you try to access the file. If you try to open a file that is currently being downloaded, iOS blocks the thread that issued the open request until the file is downloaded and available for use. Thus, if you are concerned about potential delays, check the file’s current state as needed and possibly update your user interface to reflect that the file is not yet available or is currently downloading.

For more information about the attributes you can request for URLs, see *NSURL Class Reference*.

Comment: Did you get any success to get the code working with Exact % of download and upload progress , I was just able to get the 1/0 status only.